# MySQL Trigger Setting All Other Values to NULL When Run

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have two tables, `Accounts` and `Person`:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Person_Name VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
P_Location INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Person VALUES (1,"Adam",300),(2,"Betty",10),(3,"Louis",60);

CREATE TABLE Accounts(
Person_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
Balance INT DEFAULT 200);

INSERT INTO Accounts VALUES (1,2000),(2,1350),(3,800);
```

And one trigger, `Bonuses`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Bonuses
AFTER UPDATE ON Person
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Accounts
SET Balance = CASE WHEN (SELECT P_Location FROM Person WHERE id = Person_id) = 3 THEN Balance - 150
                   WHEN (SELECT P_Location FROM Person WHERE id = Person_id) = 7 THEN Balance + 100
                   WHEN (SELECT P_Location FROM Person WHERE id = Person_id) = 15 THEN Balance - 30
                   WHEN (SELECT P_Location FROM Person WHERE id = Person_id) = 1 THEN Balance + 200
                   END;
```

And I want to make the trigger update the `Accounts` table according to certain instructions whenever the `P_Location` on the `Person` table changes to one of a select few values (3,7,15 and 1). However, as things are they result is incorrect. Assume I run the above code, the tables I get are:

**Person**

| id | Player_Name | P_Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | 300 |
| 2 | Betty | 10 |
| 3 | Louis | 60 |

**Accounts**

| Person_id | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 |
| 2 | 1350 |
| 3 | 800 |

Now if I run `UPDATE Person SET P_Location = 3 WHERE id = 1;` then the `Accounts` table should yield:

| Person_id | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **1850** |
| 2 | 1350 |
| 3 | 800 |

However, what I get is

| Person_id | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **1850** |
| 2 | **NULL** |
| 3 | **NULL** |

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that code did exactly what you said, though it wasn't what you meant!

That's the thing about `UPDATE` queries, EVERY row will get an update unless a `WHERE` clause is used to filter what actually gets modified. Nothing is found from the `CASE` with most records, so any of those will get assigned to `NULL`. To see this behavior, check this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G4Id0EsV) example.

However, there is good news, all that is needed in the trigger is to add a WHERE clause. Note that I simplified the CASE handling make use of the UPDATE trigger's `NEW` references:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Bonuses
AFTER UPDATE ON Person
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Accounts
SET Balance = CASE WHEN NEW.P_Location = 3 THEN Balance - 150
                   WHEN NEW.P_Location = 7 THEN Balance + 100
                   WHEN NEW.P_Location = 15 THEN Balance - 30
                   WHEN NEW.P_Location = 1 THEN Balance + 200
              END
WHERE Person_id = NEW.id;
```

So starting with:
[image]

Then run: `UPDATE Person SET P_Location = 3 WHERE id = 1;`

Gives:
[image]

Example [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yRlytG3y) with your tables, the simplified trigger case handling, and the output examples from the update query.